# htaccess get the first directory of a link

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently working on a php website and I am pretty unexperienced with htaccess rewrite rules and conditions. My question would be how could I get only the first directory from a link?

So for example I have a link "example.com/page1/page2/?something=something" and I need the output to be page1 so I can redirect it to index.php?p=page1

And also what would I do to get the output of "page2" or "?something=something"? So in this case I would redirect it to index.php?p=page1&ap=page2&something=something

I know that I could theoretically use:

`RewriteRule ^page1/page2$ index.php?p=page1&ap=page2`

But in this case I can't predict what page1 and page2 will be, so assume it's like a variable:

`RewriteRule ^{somevariable}/{someothervariable}$ index.php?p={somevariable}&ap={someothervariable}`

And in this case the output would be "index.php?p=page1&ap=page2".

I tried to search for this on web but I didn't really know what exactly to search for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `RewriteRule` to parse the URL...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&ap=$2 [L,QSA]

^               : Match the start of the string
 (.+?)          : Match any character one or more times; non-greedy
      /         : Match a slash
       (.+)     : Match any character one or more times
           /?   : Optionally match a slash
             $  : Match the end of the string

L               : Stops processing rules
QSA             : Append the original query string
```

**Example**

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/page1/page2?id=1435

print_r($_GET);

/*

Array
(
    [p]  => page1
    [ap] => page2
    [id] => 1435
)

*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works just the way i need it to!